# Lots of Power Shell questions, low answers; none on first page

Tags: discussion

Are Power Shell scripting questions a good fit for Super User?  Admittedly, my first thought is to ask on Stack Overflow, but I've been banned once and lost more rep than I've gained over there, so I try to avoid it at all costs. *([I'm not the only one to run afoul of SO](https://hackernoon.com/the-decline-of-stack-overflow-7cb69faa575d))*.

Looking at the first page of [results](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/powershell) for the powershell tag, I see 0 answers on all the questions.  Should I find some other forum to get help with Power Shell?

Comment: You can certainly ask your PowerShell questions here. It is specialist software and as such you shouldn't be disheartened by slow answers.

Comment: It is worth pointing out that the reason you have received downvotes on the Powershell questions you did ask, is because they were extremely low quality when they were originally submitted, even here we will want you to show your work.  My best advice leave meta commentary out of your questions.  *Worth pointing out the answer you received on SO to your last Powershell question, wasn't helpful because of the meta commentary either.*

Comment: I think the distinction is SO is probably better for *language* questions, where you want to know how some aspect of the language works, while SU is better for *task* questions, where you want to know how to perform some task (of small scope, not "write a program for me").

Comment: I can't bring myself to upvote this question because instead of simply stating "I've been banned at SO" it provides a link suggesting the ban is the SO community's fault. That's a matter of opinion and irrelevant to the  portion of the question that's eligible for discussion here on SU.Meta.

Answer (score 3):

"Light" scripting such as VBA, PowerShell and similar are considered to be on topic here as they are generally applicable to "power users" who are looking to automate tasks within their operating system or applications. Doing some light scripting would be okay, writing a whole application; not so much.

We do have a few PowerShell gurus but I do not know how active they are so it may be luck catching their attention.

SO can definitely be a good resource as there are more experienced developers there, but it probably would be on topic here as well.

Comment: You just need to say "@BenN" three times in a mirror and all your powershell worries will be gone as if by magic!

Comment: I know BenN was one of our gurus, but it wasn't going to be me who volunteered him @Burgi :P

Comment: There's always a bounty. That seems to attract attention.